# Testing websites on mobile devices

Tags: html, css, web-applications

I have this issue of testing websites on mobiles. I know that there are various ways in which I can test the responsiveness of a website including on the chrome browser and mobile phone emulators. But is there a way in which I can run the website on my phone? I could find no answer to this.

Note: The site is not online yet.

Please do help.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean as in is there a way to run the site locally off your phone so that you don't have to put it online somewhere to see it? Also, why not just use the tools that you mentioned to check the responsiveness?

Comment: Yes. I do mean running the website locally off on my phone.

Answer (score 1):

You could set up your development machine to act as a local web-server and just go the website via your LAN adress, provided the phone is connected to the same LAN.